# Admin media disappear while running django trunk in development mode

Tags: django, django-admin

I got into django recently and start playing around with the tutorials & documentation (with the development version). Everything has been fine till I decide to update again to the latest django trunk and well my admin media are not showing up at all!

After some troubles, I managed to get admin media showing by commenting out django.contrib.staticfiles. However as I do use the staticfiles app to manage my site static files, I need it to be enabled. After some troubles, I manage to get both admin media and staticfiles showing by using manage.py collectstatic to collect the admin media files to my static folder.

However is there a way for me to serve admin media in DEBUG mode easily like last time without using collect static command? as I don't want to call the collectstatic every time when django admin media files got changed in trunk? (though I don't know how often/rare that is)

Comment: See this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694449/contrib-staticfiles-and-django-admin-media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django trunk is changing how static files are served, and in fact new changes landed this morning.

You'll want to get latest again, and then start here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/