# contrib.staticfiles and Django admin media

Tags: django, django-contrib

I just switched from 1.2 to trunk (r15175 at this writing) to play with `contrib.staticfiles`, and now when using the local devserver all my admin media returns a 404.  The static media (as managed by the new contrib app) all work as expected, but I'd like to be able to use the admin with the dev server so that I don't have to restart a local apache instance when dev code changes.

Is this known behaviour?  I haven't gotten a response in IRC.

edit: Seems related to: [Admin media disappear while running django trunk in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211173/admin-media-disappear-while-running-django-trunk-in-development-mode), but there didn't seem to be an *actual* answer there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was having the same problem, finally noticed this line in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix) for `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`:

> For integration with staticfiles, this should be the same as STATIC_URL followed by 'admin/'.

Doing that fixed it for me.

**Edit 2012-03-12**: Note that as of Django 1.4, `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` has been [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin).

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing on Windows?

If so (or even if not) have a look at the Django bug [Cannot load admin interface static files when doing tutorial](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14961).  Could be the cause of your problems.